# find the very next instance of a character string using php

Tags: php

I have a string of text I am trying to parse.

```
$string ='","test","next","next2","next3"';
```

I am locating 'test' this way:

```
$pos = strpos($string, 'test');
```

That works.

What I am trying to do is find the very next instance of the " mark as the end point.

I have tried:

```
$pos_2 = strpos(substr($string,0,strpos($string,$pos)),'"');
```

But I don't get a result.

What is the best way to locate, in the above example, the next instance of the 'quote' mark (or any character / text string, for that matter) after I have located the beginning of my targeted text?

The objective in this case is to extract the term "test"

Comment: Take a look at, `PHP:explode` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php]

Comment: What do you want to happen if your string contains "testing"? Are you looking for exact quoted matches so that `"test"` should match but `"testing"` should not?

Comment: [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) also takes an optional offset argument, so find the first instance of '"' and then use that result+1 as the offset to find the second instance

Comment: Or use [strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) instead

Comment: I am looking for the character / character string immediately following the targeted text. So if I have the starting position of the targeted text (in this case 4) and the ending position (in this case 9) I can grab the text I am after. That is the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct answer to your question:

```
$p1 = strpos($string, 'test');
$p2 = strpos($string, '"', $p1);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/4S5PL84n)

If you are not always looking for `"`, and simply want the position of the character immediately following your target text, you could do this:

```
$target = 'test';
$p1 = strpos($string, $target);
$p2 = $p1 + strlen($target);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/1PbW1tkC)

---

*Keep in mind that character position will start at **0**, not **1**. So in your example, **'test'** starts at position **3** (the letter **t**), and the quote followed immediately after is at position **7**.*